# Leer una columna en Excel

Tags: excel, netbeans

Buenas Tardes, ¿cómo puedo leer una fila-columa en específico? Por ejemplo solo quiero leer dos columnas en específico, `D8` hasta `D15` y `G8` hasta `G15`.

Si me pudieran orientar o si tuvieran el codigo me sería util, gracias.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Hasta que no añadas mas información, me temo que tu pregunta quedará [en espera-¿Qué significa si una pregunta está "cerrada" o "en espera"?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), pero si editas tu pregunta y la mejoras, la comunidad puede optar por abrirla y darte una solución. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

puedes leer los valores que tienen esas celdas en especifico usando este código

Suponiendo que los datos que tienes están en la hoja 1:

```
Public Sub Lectura()
'Se declara el array que va a contener tus datos, el 500 es el maximo de datos que va a contener.

Dim Columna1(500), Columna2(500) As String
'El numero de fila donde estan tus datos

i = 8

Do While Hoja1.Cells(i, 4) <> "" 'el 4 es el numero de la columna

Columna1(i) = Hoja1.Cells(i, 4)

i = i + 1

Loop

i = 8

Do While Hoja1.Cells(i, 7) <> "" 'el 7 es el numero de la columna

    Columna2(i) = Hoja1.Cells(i, 7)

    i = i + 1

Loop

For i = 8 To 500

If Columna1(i) = "" And Columna1(i) = "" Then

Exit For

End If

Debug.Print Columna1(i) & "    " & Columna2(i)

Next

End Sub
```